# Is this function infinitly often differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following function:

$$\psi (t) =\begin{cases} \exp(-t^{-1}) &t >0 \\ 0 & t \leq 0\end{cases} .$$

I found that it is once differentiable by checking the case when $t=0$ by

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\phi(t)-\phi(0)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{\phi(t)-\phi(0)}{t}=0.$$

So I get

$$\psi' (t) =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{t^2}\exp(-t^{-1}) &t >0 \\ 0 & t \leq 0\end{cases} .$$

Is there any short reason why $\psi \in C^\infty$ or do I need to prove somehow by induction that $\psi$ is infinitely often differentiable?

Comment: The intitive reason why this function is infinitely differentiable at $0^+$ is that the inverse function $-t^{-1}$ grows quickly to minus infinity, and after taking the exponential decreases to $0$ faster than any rational fraction. For this reason, the derivatives of all orders are $0$, and the function locally behaves like $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The induction proof is short.

Show that $$
\psi^{(n)}(x) = \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}\exp(-t^{-1})
$$ where $P_n, Q_n$ are polynomials, by induction and you are done.

Comment: Sorry but it is not obvious for me how I am done when I know this. I guess I have to find a specific formula for $P_n$ and $Q_n$ and then use L'Hopital on the term $\frac{\exp(-t^{-1})}{Q_n(t)}$?

Comment: Once you have shown this, you do not need a formula for $P_n$ and $Q_n$. Just use L'Hopital rule.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is actually smooth is that the derivatives are just products of a rational function and an exponential function. This can be shown by induction, and I would say that it is rather easy but necessary.

Comment: But it is not clear if the derivative in 0 exists - right?

Comment: Lazy people (like me) may cheat by using [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: @Adam Of course you must prove that the function is differentiable at zero. And zero is the only point where you can't immediately apply standard results on differentiability.

Comment: @Siminore and how do I see this when I have shown that the derivative is a rational function times an exponential function?

Comment: In this case, by taking a limit as $x \to 0+$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way to prove what you need is to show that $$\psi^{(n)}(t) = Q(t)e^{-t^{-1}}$$ for some rational function $Q$ for all values $t>0$. It is then simple to show that $\psi^{(n)}$ is continuous at $0$ for all values of $n$.